# O que seria uma classe de serviços em um projeto MVC Java?

Tags: java, java-ee

Saberiam me dizer a diferença entre classes do pacote *"control"* em um projeto MVC e classes de serviço?

Answer (score 2):

Citando o Spring MVC como exemplo eu gosto de separar o projeto MVC em Model, View, Control e Service. O motivo é que nos meus projetos não gosto muito de deixar regras de negócio direto no Controller. Então eu delego isso ao Service. Exemplo:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/novo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView cadastrar(@Valid Cerveja cerveja, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return novo(cerveja);
    }

    /* Eu poderia deixar dezenas de linhas relativas as regras de negócio 
       de como salvar uma cerveja aqui. */
    cadastroCervejaService.salvar(cerveja);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Cerveja salva com sucesso!");

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/cervejas/novo");
}
```

Nesse código, o Controller basicamente só recebe os dados da View e retorna erros de validação (se houverem). Se não tiver erros, ele aciona o Service para salvar o registro e retorna uma mensagem de sucesso.

O ponto aqui é que toda regra de negócio de salvar um objeto **Cerveja** poderia estar dentro do Controller, porém o Controller iria receber, salvar, e retornar dados. E se houvessem muitas regras de negócio? Iria ficar muito poluído o código então eu transferi todas as regras de negócio relativas ao salvamento de uma Cerveja para o **CadastroCervejaService**. Assim, o Controller só chama.

Ao meu ver, é mais uma decisão de gosto mesmo, eu prefiro dessa forma por questão de organização.

Comment: A sim amigo, agora eu entendi, muito obrigado.

Comment: Legal. Feliz em poder ajudar.